# My Group_by in R is not working with two dimension

Tags: r, count, group-by

I am trying to understand what am I doing wrong with this code.
I wish to group by payment method and country, and then count the number of appearance (count) of the order ids.
I also need it to ignore nulls, so If a null is involve to ignore it.

```
group_data <- group_by(file$dhw.payment_method, file$dwh,country) 
M2 <- summarise(by_dhw.payment_method,
    count = n(file$dwh.order_number, file$adj.order_id, file$pay_order_id))
```

Comment: Please share some data and expected output.

Comment: Your syntax for the group_by and summarize is incorrect.  It mostly likely should be: group_data <- group_by(file, dhw.payment_method, dwh,country).  and M2 <- summarise(group_data, n()).  Please review the documentation and examples at ?group_by and ?summarise.

Comment: I just need to have a table with the extract as follow: payment_method_dwh| Country | order_date_dwh | count(dhw.order_number) | count(order_id) | count(order(pay_order_id)